# Images paths is replaced in html file but not in js files

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I am new to Grunt and all the tasks so bear with me on this one. I'm developing an AngularJS application, that I initially created through Yeoman. Since theres lot's of views I thought it would be a good idea to include all the views in the templatecache. So I installed html2js and configured it according to their GitHub read. It's working almost perfectly, except from one thing. My templates contain some references to local images. When running `grunt build` all those images's names are getting changed by `revfile`. Looking at the `dist/views` folder with all the templates, I can see that the paths is correct (the path has been replaced with the new one). However, those changes to the paths doesn't make it into the js-file that html2js generates.

How can I make Grunt replace the paths correctly in the generated html2js js-file as well? Here is the grunt initConfig parts that I think is relevant

```
filerev: {
    dist: {
        src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
    }
},

useminPrepare: {
    html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
    options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
            html: {
                steps: {
                    js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                    css: ['cssmin']
                },
                post: {}
            }
        }
    }
},

// Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
usemin: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
    css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
    options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
    }
},
****************************
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'html2js:main',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you use [grunt-angular-templates](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates) instead? It is designed precisely to insert views into the `$templateCache`.

I have never had any problems with relative paths.

You can even pair it with `https://github.com/mgcrea/grunt-nginclude` to inline "partials".

Comment: Thank you for your response! This would probably work. However this isn't actually a solution to the problem, but rather a workaround. Also I'm not quite sure that this is a problem with html2js, but a problem with the file revisioning task.